# Python time.ctime() format: 0-padding or space-padding

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, formatting, ctime

Two different computers (same python version) return different formatting for `time.ctime()`. One returns

```
"Sun May  6 14:04:28 2018"
```

with 2 spaces before the day of month; the other returns

```
"Sun May 06 14:04:28 2018"
```

with a space and a zero. I feel like it's dictated either by OS or by C lib. Does anyone know what this depends upon?

P.S.: I know how to fix it in the code, I'm looking for a root cause of such behavior.

Comment: I'm positive they are both 2.7.13

Comment: Yes. win 8 and win server 2012. But another server 12 also returned a format differently than my server 2012.

Comment: I’ll try reinstalling python, actually. I haven’t run sys version on the second server, will check it. Thanx.

Comment: @KatyaDenef How should that make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c contains the relevant code:

```
static PyObject *
_asctime(struct tm *timeptr)
{
    …

    return PyUnicode_FromFormat("%s %s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d", …
```

In words: The said version of Python produces a three character number behind the month, without any zeros. So it is either `Dec  9` or `Dec 10`.

<del>I could not manage to find a version different, but probably one of the versions you use does something like `"%s %s %02d…`, putting an explicit space and a two-digit day.</del>

Update: By going back the "blame chain", I could find https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/2427ab9d6f132224d6ee4a2b7f00b9d69ba6c0a3/Modules/timemodule.c which indeed calls the libc `asctime()` function. Up to then, the function indeed was OS dependent.

The relevant changeset can be reached under https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b9588b528a48302a4884d0500caec71f1c59280c of 2011-01-04 and, as far as I understand the tags, was backported up to v2.7.4. If your version is older than that, that explains something.